# How to Mock ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: java, unit-testing, aspectj, spock

I am trying to writing a Spock specification that test an AspectJ advice class. Therefore I need a mock instance of `org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint` class.

```
void "Verify client capability mechanism"() {

   given:
   def pointCut = Mock(ProceedingJoinPoint)

   and: 'the method calls would have the following arguments'
   pointCut.getArgs() >> ['xxx', 1L, 44] as Object[] // this is where the error happens

   when: 'the advice gets called'
   def retVal = new ClientCapabilitySecurityAdvice().verifyUserCanPerformActionOnCurrentClient(pointCut)

   then: 'the call may proceed'
   1 * pointCut.getArgs()
   1 * pointCut.proceed() >> 'Hello'
   retVal == 'Hello'
}
```

For some reason I am not able to define a return value on `getArgs()` on my mock instance. I get this error message.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method rightShift() on null object
```

What is the proper way to mock the `ProceedingJointPoint` interface? Can someone help me on this?

PS: Merry christmas to you :)

**Update (Solution according Peter)**

```
void "Verify client capability mechanism"() {                                                            

    given:                                                                                               
    def pointCut = Mock(ProceedingJoinPoint)                                                             

    when: 'the advice gets called'                                                                       
    def retVal = new ClientCapabilitySecurityAdvice().verifyUserCanPerformActionOnCurrentClient(pointCut)

    then: 'the method calls would have the following arguments'                                          
    1 * pointCut.getArgs() >> ['xxx', 1L, 44]                                                            

    and: 'the actual return value is set'                                                                
    1 * pointCut.proceed() >> 'Hello'                                                                    

    and: 'the call may proceed'                                                                          
    retVal == 'Hello'                                                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot two mistakes:

1. `pointCut.getArgs() >> ['xxx', 1L, 44] as Object[]` is the same as `(pointCut.getArgs() >> ['xxx', 1L, 44]) as Object[]`, which is not a mock interaction. To fix this, you need to use parens on the RHS. Probably you can even omit the coercion because Groovy will do it automatically.
2. Stubbing and mocking of the same method call needs to happen in the same statement: `then: 1 * pointCut.getArgs() >> (['xxx', 1L, 44] as Object[])`. See the mocking chapter at http://docs.spockframework.org for more on this.

Comment: Thank you Peter. That did the job.